# Trivial HTML page crashes browser when using IE11, but all other browsers run fine?

Tags: internet-explorer, cross-browser

I have a Windows guest VM in a Linux host that I'm using to test IE compatibility on my site. The host accepts requests from `0.0.0.0:3000` (any IP, port 3000), and is mapped to `192.168.167.1` in the guest using host-only networking.

When I visit `192.168.167.1:3000` in the guest, using Chrome, Safari, Firefox, or Opera, everything is fine and the site works as expected. When I view the same site in IE, it crashes the browser:

[image]

All the HTML validates correctly as HTML5. Any hints as to what could be going on?

Comment: What does the "View problem details" say?

Comment: @Roman Clicking it causes the window to crash again and generates a new, identical dialog.